# pandas series: why series[-1] = error and series[0] = result

Tags: pandas, indexing

Given a series like `pd.Series([1,2,3,4])`
To get the first value I can do:

```
first = series[0]
```

But to get the last value like `last = series[-1]` produces an error.
I need to do `last = series.iloc[-1]`
I don't understand why. (Why do I don't need `first = series.iloc[0]` or can do `last = series[-1]`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, let's do a little experiement.

```
s = pd.Series([1,2,3,4],index=[9,8,7,6]) 
s.index
```

Output:

```
Int64Index([9, 8, 7, 6], dtype='int64')
```

If you have this series, even S[0] will give an error.  But you can do S[9], S[8], etc..

```
s[9]
1
s[8]
2
s[0]
KeyError: 0
s[-1]
KeyError: -1
```

When you are using s[0], you are using the index value which does not exist.  Same for s[-1] in this case.

When you want to use -1 to refer to the last item, you can still do it but like this:

```
s = pd.Series([1,2,3,4])
s[-1:]
```

Output:

```
3    4
dtype: int64
```

You are telling the series, you want the last item till the end, not specifing the actual index value.  In this case, 3 is the index, 4 is the value.

And if you want to refer to the 2nd last item, like this:

```
s = pd.Series([1,2,3,4])
s[-2:-1]
```

Output:

```
2    3
dtype: int64
```